# Cosa significa "scoppiare a tempo" riferito a una bomba?

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *Oro* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto questo brano, che fa riferimento a quando l'autore fu catturato come partigiano (grassetto mio):

> Ci fecero salire, sedere separati, ed io avevo militi tutto intorno, seduti ed in piedi, che non badavano a noi e continuavano a cantare. Uno, proprio davanti a me, mi voltava la schiena, e dalla cintura gli pendeva una bomba a mano di quelle tedesche, col manico di legno, che **scoppiano a tempo**: avrei potuto benissimo levare la sicura, tirare la funicella e farla finita insieme con diversi di loro, ma non ne ebbi il coraggio.

Nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tempo) ho trovato

> Con uso generico, *in tempo*, meno com. *a tempo*, in tempo utile (contrapp. a *tardi*, *troppo tardi*): *se n’è accorto, si è ritirato, si è pentito in t.*; spec. con i verbi *essere, arrivare, fare*: *se vuoi rescindere il contratto, sei ancora in t.*; *sono in t. a presentare la domanda*?; *a farlo, siamo sempre in t.*, non c’è fretta; *arrivi proprio in t., a t.* (anche nella forma del superl.: *sei arrivato in tempissimo*); *farò in t. a prendere il treno?*; *facciamo in t. a prendere un caffè prima che cominci lo spettacolo?*; *feci appena in t. a scendere, che la vettura si rimise in moto*.

Tuttavia, non mi sembra che questo significato abbia senso riferito allo scoppiare di una bomba: si tratterebbe di una bomba che non scoppia troppo tardi?

Per questa ragione vi chiedo: che vuol dire "scoppiare a tempo" riferito a una bomba?

Comment: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stielhandgranate_24 La distinzione è fra granate a tempo (che scoppiano dopo un certo lasso di tempo) e a urto (che scoppiano quando cadono a terra).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per "scoppio a tempo" si intende che lo scoppio è programmato per avvenire dopo un certo periodo di tempo.
Nelle bombe a mano lo scoppio è sempre ritardato per poter eseguire il lancio in sicurezza.